# Random gap between elements or divs

Tags: css, html, random, gaps-in-visuals

There is a weird gap appearing between the elements here. I would prefer to have them flush together. Any idea how to fix this?

[LINK](http://revelationtechs.com/steve/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you haven't styled those elements which leave it up to the browser to decide. Chrome for instance decide to input margins on the p-element.

```
p { ...
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
... }
```

Use a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file and you will both fix this particular problem but problably many many similair situations in your future as a web developer.

Answer (score 7):

That's because you haven't provided any css for the tags `h1,p`. So, browser is adding default margin bottom and top. So, add this to css -

```
p, h1 { margin: 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a margin/padding issue as stated by others. What I suggest if you are just getting started and haven't developed any habits yet is to always include a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file. This will get rid of all the browser defaults and allow you to start fresh.

Answer (score 1):

fixes for inline elements are:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

or

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

display:block;

for images

Comment: In my case This one helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found my mysterious white spaces.

Don't do this:

```
echo "<div>
blah blah blah
</div>"
```

Instead:

```
echo "<div>"
          ."blah blah blah"
     ."</div>";
```

Just clean up your code of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, as to which kind of /gap/ you are referring, but a simple CSS rule like margin:0; padding:0; might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use a CSS reset file, like the one you can find on YUI:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

If you do end up using the YUI CSS Reset, make sure you set your background color on the HTML tag as well since YUI's CSS Reset turns it white.

```
html {
   background:black;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background: black;
}
```